# Setting a key if it's not set - which way is the most efficient?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the most efficient way of checking if a key is set on an object, and if not, set it to a given value? Keep in mind this is only relevant in high-performance cases

*Let's assume `someCostlyOperation()` takes a lot of CPU time to compute and never returns a falsy value*

**Method #1**

```
if(!myObj.myKey) myObj.myKey = someCostlyOperation();
```

**Method #2**

```
myObj.myKey = myObj.myKey || someCostlyOperation();
```

Summary:

- Method #1 makes a check to see if myKey is falsy. If `undefined`, it will then set it to `someCostlyOperation()`.
- Method #2 doesn't have the condition, but always reassigns `myObj.myKey`. If falsy, it sets it to `someCostlyOperation()`.

The difference in performance might not be significant, but in nested loops where this line is evaluated tens of thousands of times, every little optimization matters in order to lower the execution time and improve the overall application performance.

I assume method #1 is faster, since it makes the same kind of check on `myObj.myKey` that method #2 makes, without, however, uselessly reassigning it every time. I might be wrong though, since I don't know about all the internal optimizations Javascript interpreters make to code like this (in my case it runs with Node.js).

What is the best way to accomplish this?

---

***EDIT***

Arnauld in the comments suggested a third method. Here it is :

**Method #3**

```
!myObj.myKey && (myObj.myKey = someCostlyOperation());
```

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I made that comment before reading your assumption, and deleted it before your reply! Still though, I can't think of any reason #2 would be faster. It will either be that they are equal, or that #1 is faster. I look forward to someone answering.

Comment: @Jonah That's what I think too, I don't think #2 can be more efficient either. But I'm not 100% sure, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking? Javascript optimization behavior can vary between versions of the same browsers even, so there is no way to know without testing.

Comment: While we're at it, method #3 : `!myObj.myKey && (myObj.myKey = someCostlyOperation());`

Comment: @Arnauld Interesting. Added it to the main post.

Comment: Curious as to why we're not checking props with: myObj.hasOwnProperty(myKey) since this prevents an unwanted search into the prototype chain

Answer (score 4):

It's basically a tie between all 3 methods.

```
(function(){
  var myObj = { };

  var time1,time2,testTime1,testTime2,testTime3,test1Wins=0,test2Wins=0,test3Wins=0,noWinner=0;
  function someCostlyOperation(){
    for(var i=0; i<100000; i++){

    }
    return {};
  }


  function method1(){
    if(!myObj.myKey) myObj.myKey = someCostlyOperation();
  }

  function method2(){
    myObj.myKey = myObj.myKey || someCostlyOperation();
  }

  function method3(){
    !myObj.myKey && (myObj.myKey = someCostlyOperation());
  }


  for(var i=0;i<10000;i++){

  delete myObj.myKey;
  time1 = performance.now();
  method3();
  time2 = performance.now();
  testTime1 = time2-time1;

  delete myObj.myKey;
  time1 = performance.now();
  method2();
  time2 = performance.now();
  testTime2 = time2-time1;

  delete myObj.myKey;
  time1 = performance.now();
  method3();
  time2 = performance.now();
  testTime3 = time2-time1;


  if(testTime1<testTime2 && testTime1<testTime3){
      test1Wins++;
  }
  else if(testTime2<testTime3 && testTime2<testTime1){
     test2Wins++;
  }
  else if(testTime3<testTime1 && testTime3<testTime2){
      test3Wins++;
  }
    else{
        noWinner++;
    }

  }

  console.log("test1Wins:",test1Wins);
  console.log("test2Wins:",test2Wins);
  console.log("test3Wins:",test3Wins);
  console.log("noWinners:",noWinner);
})();
```

Comment: Could you process the same test it in reverse order? I mean, 2nd method first and 1st method second. Just to be sure that it's not due to some 'warm up' effect of the JS engine.

Comment: Instead of using `new Date()` try `Date.now()` or even more appropriate, `performance.now()` to get a higher timestamp resolution

Comment: I just tried @Hoyen's tests both reversed and with performance.now(). Same results.  Method 2 is always faster than method 1.

Comment: I switched the order too and method 2 mostly wins

Comment: I don't think the right thing is tested here - both method lines in the code are executed only once. What we need to know is how it does when those lines are executed tens of thousands of times.

Comment: I editted my code. But there are two results. If the key doesn't exist method 2 is faster. If the key exists, method 1 is faster

Comment: Nevermind. both scenarios with or without the key there, method 2 wins most of the time. I tested it wrong with the key.

Comment: I still don't think the right thing was tested, because you reset `myObj.myKey` every time - here is how I would do it : http://pastebin.com/NKeympyC. It seems that no matter which one I execute last, it wins most of the times ... There definitely seems to be some kind of warm up altering the results

Comment: @SamuelBolduc my test is accurate. No matter the order. I tested the best and worst case scenarios with it and the results has method 2 winning. But if you aren't happy with that, then I don't have any solution for you other than to do what you feel is best.

Comment: @SamuelBolduc I saw your code and the way you set it up is that it will only run through someCostlyOperation() the first iteration and then the rest, since it is set, will just ignore it. Is that really how you want the test to run???

Comment: And I just added method3 and that wins way more than the other 2 hands down. I recommend method3

Comment: @Hoyen yep, that's how I would like it to run. In a real use case, I use this line deep in nested loops to set the key only if it's not set. So by design, it will only run once and then what matters is how we do the check to decide whether or not run `someCostlyOperation()`

Comment: There was a flaw in my test. I didn't test for a tie. I added the code to check for ties and the results are basically they are all pretty even.

Comment: @SamuelBolduc well that's not how tests usually are done. You typically test for worst and best case scenarios. But regardless, the data from the updated code pretty much says it doesn't matter which method you choose.